# Dealing with variable number of keyword arguments to send requests

Tags: python, python-2.7

Related to `Python 2.7`

---

How would one go about building a request through a variable number of `kwargs` when using `requests`.

I am using the `requests` module to directly interact with a REST API which requires a variable number of keyword arguments in order to be successful.

Rather than re-writing the same GET/POST request code, I would like to maintain it within a single `api` class. However handling the variable number of arguments seems to boil down to a series of `if-else` statements which isn't particularly readable.

For example:

```
def request(self):
    try:
        if self.data:
            request = requests.post(url=self.url, headers=self.headers,
                 data=self.data, timeout=self.timeout, verify=False)
        else:
            request = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, 
                    timeout=self.timeout, verify=False)
    ...
    ...
```

Preferably the request properties are build over time and them passed through a single GET or POST request (granted, the above code would still be require but that is minor).

Comment: I've just read your question briefly but what you're looking for might be something along the lines of `def request(self, *args, **kwargs):` and then pass `args` straight into `requests.post(args)` or use a dictionary if possible.

Comment: @Torxed - I don't believe I would be able to pass `*args` directly using `requests`. I thought of that approach however certain keyword arguments affect both `GET` & `POST` (e.g Cookie) :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the attributes default to the same values as arguments to `requests.post` (basically, `None`), than you can safely pass all of them as keyword arguments:

```
def request(self):
    try:
        request = requests.post(url=self.url, headers=self.headers,
                                data=self.data, timeout=self.timeout,
                                verify=False)
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is indeed useful and probably sufficient for the time being. I'll leave the question open for a while to see if someone comes up with a better response